# Thread in C++ DLL called by EPrime causes exception

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll

I have a DLL written in C++, which exports a function that calls a thread. If the function returns before the thread terminates (which is the standard usecase), EStudio crashes. My platform is Windows 10, 64 bits, but the DLL is compiled in x86 mode.

The function is thus declared in EPrime:

```
Declare Function moop stdcall Lib "meep.dll" () As Long
Dim oPtr As Long
oPtr = moop()
```

and the DLL code looks like this:

```
void* event_loop_func(void* eye_tracker)
{
    Sleep(3000);

    return 0;
}

void * __stdcall moop()
{
    void * hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,                                       // default security attributes
        0,                                          // use default stack size
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)event_loop_func,           // thread function name
        NULL,                                   // argument to thread function
        0,                                          // use default creation flags
        NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Any advice on how to run a thread from the DLL without crashing EStudio?

Comment: What is the bitness of application that calls moop() function? Just to check various compatibility issues, comment the CreateThread code and just return NULL from function moop() and check if things work.

Comment: Without knowing this environment it would seem that when "moop" returns, EStudio unloads the dll. You might need to manually call `LoadLibrary` on yourself and `event_loop_func` would end with `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` to ensure the dll remains loaded long enough.